# LINQ to Entity dynamic Filter (Navigation and 2 Detail Entities)

Tags: c#, wpf, filter, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I am confused and already damaged (head --> wall). I am trying to rewrite my question and mybe its bit better.

xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveCaptionBrushKey}}" ShowGridLines="True" DataContext="{StaticResource hOTYearViewSource}" >
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Txt_Material" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="340,30,0,0" TextChanged="MaterialFilter_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Watermark="Material Filter"></xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Txt_Nr1" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="340,60,0,0" TextChanged="MaterialFilter_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Watermark="Nr1 Filter"></xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Txt_Nr2" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="450,60,0,0" TextChanged="MaterialFilter_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Watermark="Nr2 Filter"></xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Txt_Nr3" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="340,90,0,0" TextChanged="MaterialFilter_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Watermark="Nr3 Filter"></xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Txt_Nr4" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="450,90,0,0" TextChanged="MaterialFilter_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Watermark="Nr4 Filter"></xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Txt_Nr5" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="340,120,0,0" TextChanged="MaterialFilter_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Watermark="Nr5 Filter"></xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
            <xctk:WatermarkTextBox x:Name="Txt_Nr6" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="450,120,0,0" TextChanged="MaterialFilter_TextChanged" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Watermark="Nr6 Filter"></xctk:WatermarkTextBox>
            <ListView x:Name="hOTYearListView" DisplayMemberPath="Year_ID" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="10,30,0,0" SelectedValuePath="Year_ID" SelectionMode="Single" Width="100" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <ListView x:Name="hOTOrderListView"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource hOTYearHOTOrderViewSource}}" Margin="150,30,0,0" SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Width="170" Height="150">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Bestellnummer" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bestellnummer}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Positionen" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Positionen}" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>

            </ListView>

            <ListView x:Name="orderPosListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource hOTYearHOTOrderOrderPosViewSource}}" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                      Margin="10,200,10,10" SelectionMode="Single" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingStyle}" AlternationCount="2">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Position" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Position}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Nr1"  DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr1}"/>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Nr2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr2}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Nr3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr3}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Nr4" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr4}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Nr5" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr5}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Nr6" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nr6}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Benennnung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Benennnung}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Material" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Material}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Auftrag" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Auftrag}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Härtegrad" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Härtegrad}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Stück" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Stk}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Eht" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Eht}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Ri" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Ri}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Gewicht in Kg" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Gewicht}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Kosten" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding kosten}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Reale Kosten" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding kostenreal}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Lieferdatum" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Lieferdatum, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Termin" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Termin, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="geliefert" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding geliefert, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Rechnung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Rechn, StringFormat='dd.MM.yyyy'}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Bemerkung" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Bemerkung}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Link">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=Link}" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_OnRequestNavigate">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Link}"/>
                                        </Hyperlink>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

            <Button x:Name="Btn_Back10" Content="Zurück" Height="25" Width="100" Click="Btn_Back_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" FontSize="16" />
        </Grid>
```

my entity using is something like this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt715492.aspx

i use 3 listviews and 3 entities

i see evrthing its ok

but i must use a filter for it

and theres my problem.

i can filter my master entity it works for me but if i try to filter my details it wont work.

i try it with:

```
var query = (from HY in dataEntities.HOTYear
             join HO in dataEntities.HOTOrder on HY.Year_ID equals HO.YearID
             join OP in dataEntities.OrderPos on HO.Order_ID equals OP.OrderID
             where (OP.Material == "2842")
             select HY).ToList().Distinct();
```

I get the right year, I can navigate but alle details are not filtered

I try something like this:

```
var query = dataEntities.HOTYear.Select(y => new
                {
                    y.Year_ID,
                    HOTOrder = y.HOTOrder.Select(o => new
                    {
                        o.Bestellnummer,
                        o.Positionen,
                        OrderPos = o.OrderPos.Where(p => p.Material == Txt_Material.Text)
                    })
                });
```

but only my last detail is filtered and my navigation still works.

**My question**: how can I use my filter for all and create a dynamic filter for all 7 filter options?

Answer (score -1):

you two way :

1- use the linq query like this :(from t in context.table where t.field=="something" select t).tolist(); 
2- use the linq methods: context.table.where(w=> w.field == "something").tolist(); 
as your like

Comment: Hey and thx for ur help
was testing it too

i try that:
var querry = (from HY in dataEntities.HOTYear
                          join HO in dataEntities.HOTOrder on HY.Year_ID equals HO.YearID
                          join OP in dataEntities.OrderPos on HO.Order_ID equals OP.OrderID
                          where (OP.Material == "2842")
                          select HY).ToList().Distinct();

but only the master one is fitered

Comment: theres no problem to do it
it work for to do it with 1 entity and 1 listview only
my problem is to do it with 3 entities and 3 listview nad navigation property
my filter isnt right now and iam confused allready.
let me rewrite my question

Comment: @fkr.ayoub This question isn't about query syntax vs. method syntax. Moreover, what you show isn't even proper syntax. Please either delete your answer or turn it into something that *does* answer the question.